# How to do this number line using tikz?

Tags: latex, tikz

[image: second-order finite-difference method]

I'm new to tikz and drawing using LaTeX. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale = 1.5]

    % draw axis
    \draw [-] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
    \draw (-3,-0.2) -- (-3,0.2);
    \draw (3,-0.2) -- (3,0.2);
    \draw (1.8,-0.2) -- (1.8,0.2); % u_5
    \draw (0.6,-0.2) -- (0.6,0.2); % u_4
    \draw (-0.6,-0.2) -- (-0.6,0.2); % u_3
    \draw (-1.8,-0.2) -- (-1.8,0.2); % u_2
    
    %u1
    \node [below] at (-3,-0.32) {$x_1 = 0$};
    \node [above] at (-3,0.2) {$u_1 = 1$};
    
    %u2
    \node [below] at (-1.8,-0.2) {$x_2 = \frac{1}{4}$};
    \node [above] at (-1.8,0.2) {$u_2$};
    
    %u3
    \node [below] at (-0.6,-0.2) {$x_3 = \frac{1}{2}$};
    \node [above] at (-0.6,0.2) {$u_3$};
    
    %u4
    \node [below] at (0.6,-0.2) {$x_4 = \frac{3}{4}$};
    \node [above] at (0.6,0.2) {$u_4$};
    
    %u5
    \node [below] at (1.8,-0.32) {$x_4 = 1$};
    \node [above] at (1.8,0.2) {$u_5$};
    
    %u6
    \node [below] at (3,-0.32) {$x_6$};
    \node [above] at (3,0.2) {Ghost Node};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
```